# Can you stream the bytes in file to any program?

Tags: java, file, encryption

So I have this idea but i dont know if it is possible...

Here is the idea:

> As an example i will use a .doc file and word. I want to encrypt this
>   .doc file to a .encrypt file. Then in my program decrypt the file and force word to load the file object.

Or do I need to decrypt the file, write it to the HDD and then open/edit the file save it, and then encrypt it again?

Or is there another approach which I havent thought of?

Hope some of you can help :)

Comment: Decrypt, store to disc, exec word with path pointing to that file.

Comment: So there is no way I can bypass the step which makes the file vulnerable?

Comment: Its still vulnerable when its loaded into the application, particularly if the program creates an automatic backup/change control or the data gets swapped out to disk.

Comment: @JonasLagoni check the docs for `word.exe` or help if it has any, and see if it is possible to pass whole document via CLI eg as base64 data. Don't expect ppl here to do ALL the work for you - this basic reasearch is something that you should start with in the first place.

Comment: I get that the application the file is loaded is vulnerable. But it cant be more vulnerable then have the file placed decrypted on the hdd?

Comment: @Antoniossss I am not expecting ppl to do the work for me, I simply want to know if it is possible to stream the data from one program to the other without having to save it on the hdd... Because so fare I cant seem to find any information about it. Just want to be pointed in the right direction :)

Comment: @JonasLagoni yes you do. You asked, how to do everything from the beginning to the end without showing that you have made any effort beforehand. That is why you have downlvotes and question will be closed eventually.

Comment: So do you want my search history or? I cant show you what i havent found.

Comment: There is no general solution, most applications expect to load data from a physical path.

Comment: @AlexK.: most application do, but Microsoft's ones don't require it: you can embed a word document in an excel one, and there is one single storage for both, each being processed by its proper application.

Comment: @SergeBallesta So for Microsoft programs I can research your answer, but else I might need to change some opensource programs to fit my need? And if I need to open a, lets say photoshop file, I would need to store it temp on my hdd?

Comment: Most applications won't have the ability to accept a stream of bytes. You would have to decrypt your bytes, write them to the file system, then get Word to open that file. It will still be unencrypted at some point regardless of what you do, as you don't have control over how other programs process files/bytes. Sounds a little like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @ManoDestra You might be right. Just wanted to know if anybody had any "theories" I could look into since i couldnt find anyone myself.

One thought i guess could work. If I only used opensource programs I could implement the decryption in that program instead of trying to force the program to load the decrypted file.

Comment: @ManoDestra: COM-OLE allows to not store an object in its own file but let its container to provide a moniker for its persistence. It may be an X-Y problem, but it has a direct solution.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Excellent point and a nice potential solution. Just depends on support in each application though. May work for the given example of Word, but not necessarily universally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but there is some work to achieve it. Microsoft Object Linking and Embedding (OLE) and Common Object Model (COM) provide everything you need. AFAIK, it will not be portable to any other architecture, but you can build it on Windows. A detailed explaination with code examples would be way too large for a SO answer, so I will just give pointers.

What you need here is to build a COM client that will be able to support a Word object as a COM server. Your client should be able to provide an encrypted storage through a custom moniker. It should work, because it is more or less the way you can include a Word object in an Excell sheet for example.

If you have no to little experience in COM programming, do not try that directly. If you do not know Microsoft Advanced Template Library, do not try either. IMHO the requirements are:

- a MSCV environment with its full documentation
- examples of COM clients and servers - follow tutorials in MSVC doc if you have not them already built
- examples of persistance of embedded objects - idem follow tutorials

Once you have all that, you should be able to specify a and build a dedicated  OLE client containing a Word object and providing encrypted storage for it. Good luck in your quest...

---

But do not expect that to be much safer than unencrypting a file processing it through Word and encryting it again when done. Ok it will be immune to script kiddies looking for .doc or .docx files, but as soon as the document is loaded in Word for edition, the Word program can be manipulated (through automation, or by direct sending of keyboard messages) by an evil piece of code. From a security point or view, if there is something you cannot trust in your machine, it is no longer (only) yours.

Comment: Thanks for those details, I will look into it! One question, for me it sounds like this would only work microsoft programs? The only solution I am looking for, is to make sure the files stay as safe as possible while they are decrypted. And one step of the way could be not to store them on the HDD.